# Diamond structures in SQL

Tags: sql, join, sqlalchemy

## Question

Given the following table structure, where `B` and `C` provide auxiliary information and serve as the association tables between `A` and `D`.

```
A <- B
^    |
|    v
C -> D
```

Is it possible, for a given record `a` in `A`, to retrieve the data in `B` **and** `C` that map it to a given value, or set of values, in `D` that are related to `a` ?

### Example Scenario

As an example consider that `a`, a record in `A`, represents a company and that `D` contains the products it might buy or sell and that `B` and `C` represent the purchase and sales prices thereof. So for a given company `a` it would be quite reasonable to require a list of purchase and sales prices, which requires a combination of `B`, `C` and `D`.

My first thought is to join both `B` and `C` together into a compound table. Then use the compound table to map the record(s) in `A` to those in `D`. Something like the following might suffice :

```
# SQL Alchemy
prices = B.join(C, B.a_id==C.a_id and B.d_id==C.d_id)
A.join(prices, A.id==prices.a_id).join(D, D.id == prices.D_id)

# SQL (like)
SELECT B.A_ID OR C.A_ID as A_ID, B.PRICE AS B, C.PRICE AS C, B.D_ID OR C.D_ID 
as D_ID,
FROM B, C
WHERE B.D_ID = C.D_ID AND B.A_ID = C.A_ID
```

Though I'm not certain this is the best way to go about this.

At the suggestion of Gordon Linoff I have included the following data as an example :

```
         A                               B             
  -----------------             ----------------------  
   ID |   Name                   A_ID | D_ID | Price   
  -----------------             ----------------------  
    1 | A Company                   1 |    1 |    10   
  -----------------                 1 |    3 |    30   
                                ----------------------

         C                                D                               
----------------------             -----------------                                  
 A_ID | D_ID | Price                 ID |   Name                                     
----------------------             -----------------                                  
    1 |    2 |   -20                  1 | Apples                                     
    1 |    3 |   -30                  2 | Bananas
----------------------                3 | Cucumbers
                                   -----------------
```

with which the desired result would be as follows

```
                         Result (A.ID=1)
             -------------------------------------
                   A     |  B  |  C  |    D
             -------------------------------------
               A Company |  10 |   - | Apples
               A Company |   - | -20 | Bananas
               A Company |  30 | -30 | Cucumbers
             -------------------------------------
```

### Minimum Working (Broken) Example

At the suggestion of Phillipxy here is a minimal working <kbd>[example (Click here @Phillipxy)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1283501/diamond-structures-in-sql)</kbd>.

### Notes

- I've used SQL Alchemy notation above but I'm happy with a pure SQL answer too.
- I've looked at related questions and it seems common to join `D` with both `C` and `D` table but I haven't spotted any that then join the compound table back to `A` e.g. `A -> (B + D + C)`. More so I haven't seen any answers that zip `B` and `C` together such that one can then join `A` to `D` e.g. `A -> (B + C) -> D`. If there is a better means of combining all four tables in the manner asked I'm open to suggestions.
- Clicking the <kbd>[example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1283501/diamond-structures-in-sql)</kbd> button will take you to the S.E. query environment with a mock example (Unfortunately one is prevented from setting up foreign keys on temporary tables)

Comment: This uses vague terms. I guess the arrows are FKs? FKs & other constraints are not needed & need not be known to query. A table (base or query result) represents a relationship/association & a query result table's relationship/association is constructed via AND, AND condition, OR, AND NOT & EXISTS from the base tables' relationships/associations by using (respectively) JOIN, WHERE condition, UNION, EXCEPT & SELECT. Knowing such table meanings is necessary & sufficient to query. When a constraint holds, some expressions return the same result as others that otherwise wouldn't.

Comment: @philipxy The arrows are meant to represent foreign keys; it is the best I could manage with ASCII (Is there a means of providing entity relationship diagrams ?). I also added a link to an MWE.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). (DDL gives ERD content.) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial. Follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design & querying. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question where stuck. PS For code questions give a [mre]--which includes cut & paste & runnable code; smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output & clear specification & explanation.

Comment: @philipxy I have provided a single question, an MWE, example data (Which lead to an answer that didn't quite match my intent so I revised the question and apologized accordingly) and a mock up (You have to click it to access it though). As SQL is not my primary domain the terminology might be out some but I have used the same terms as in the documentation of my chosen framework, SQL Alchemy. If this is covered in an introductory textbook then I'm happy to have a link/reference for it, I haven't seen this exact scenario in mine though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your solution is fine, personally I would prefer COALESCE to shorten it a bit

```
SELECT A.Name, M.Sales, M.Purchase, D.Name
FROM A JOIN (
   SELECT 
   COALESCE(B.A_ID, C.A_ID) AS A_ID,      
   B.Price as Sales,
   C.Price as Purchase,
   COALESCE(B.D_ID, C.D_ID) AS D_ID
   FROM B FULL OUTER JOIN C ON B.A_ID = C.A_ID 
                           AND B.D_ID = C.D_ID) M ON A.ID = M.A_ID
JOIN D ON D.ID = M.D_ID
```

The approach of John M. Owen is possible too, just add second table

```
SELECT A.NAME AS A, B.PRICE AS B, C.PRICE AS C, D.NAME AS D 
FROM A
CROSS JOIN D
LEFT JOIN B ON B.D_ID = D.ID AND B.A_ID = A.ID
LEFT JOIN C ON C.D_ID = D.ID AND C.A_ID = A.ID
WHERE B.PRICE IS NOT NULL OR C.PRICE IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

assuming that B and C are each unique over (a_id,d_id):

```
SELECT B.PRICE AS B, C.PRICE AS C, D.NAME AS D
FROM D
LEFT JOIN B ON B.D_ID = D.ID
LEFT JOIN C ON C.D_ID = D.ID
WHERE B.PRICE IS NOT NULL OR C.PRICE IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was correct for the original example posed. My real issue, and the reason I posted, is that I get stuck tying everything back to ``A``. I have since updated the question to reflect this, my apologies if I'm messing you around.

Comment: I've marked Antonin Lejsek's answer as correct since it presents the combination of both methods. Thanks once again though.

Answer (score 0):

I found I can stitch the two tables, `B` and `C`, together as follows :

```
SELECT 
   (case when B.A_ID is not null
         then
             B.A_ID
         else
             C.A_ID
         end) A_ID,
   B.Price,
   C.Price,
   (case when B.D_ID is not null
         then
             B.D_ID
         else
             C.D_ID
         end) D_ID
FROM B FULL OUTER JOIN C ON B.A_ID = C.A_ID AND B.D_ID = C.D_ID;
```

combining the above with tables `A` and `D` gives one the following query :

```
SELECT A.Name, M.Sales, M.Purchase, D.Name
FROM A
JOIN (
SELECT 
   (case when B.A_ID is not null
        then
            B.A_ID
        else
            C.A_ID
            end) A_ID,
   B.Price as Sales,
   C.Price as Purchase,
   (case when B.D_ID is not null
        then
            B.D_ID
        else
            C.D_ID
            end) D_ID
   FROM B FULL OUTER JOIN C ON B.A_ID = C.A_ID AND B.D_ID = C.D_ID) M ON A.ID = M.A_ID
JOIN D ON D.ID = M.D_ID
```

This reads a little like the love child of Frankenstein's monster and a cast member of Jaws that never made it to the credits was encoded as ASCII; so I'll wait for a better suggestion before assigning the Tick.